# WiFi / WLAN: WPA2 authentication appears to be successful, but dhclient won't get a response

Tags: wifi, dhcp

I'm trying to use a USB WiFi adapter to connect to a wireless router.

I assume the adapter is brought to life with the correct driver, because `# iwconfig` gives some reasonable output:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"MYNET"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:1C:4A:A6:8F:0E   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:49   Missed beacon:0
```

Also, I assume that the authentication between the router and my adapter was successful, because `# wpa_cli status` says *"COMPLETED"*:

```
Selected interface 'wlan0'
bssid=00:1c:4a:a6:8f:0e
ssid=MYNET
id=0
mode=station
pairwise_cipher=CCMP
group_cipher=TKIP
key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
wpa_state=COMPLETED
address=00:0d:0b:35:ca:14
```

**Question 1:** With information like this, am I correct to assume that my adapter runs fine as interface *wlan0*, and that the router has accepted my key and is ready and willing to establish a connection? I am not having any WPA2 authentication issues?

Now, to use *wlan0*, it needs an ip address, and the router is set up as a DHCP server, with DHCP addresses ranging from 192.168.2.100 to 192.168.2.199. As far as I understand the DHCP negotiation process, dhclient should work with the defaults, i.e. it broadcasts at 255.255.255.255, and the router should answer as 0.0.0.0, finally issuing an available address. Hoewever, `# dhclient wlan0 -v`, just gives up after a while:

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2
Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlan0/00:0d:0b:35:ca:14
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/00:0d:0b:35:ca:14
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

**Question 2:** (Probably the harder part to answer?) Why is the broadcast DHCPDISCOVER not getting a proper reply, i.e. a DHCPOFFER?

**Some more info and hints on possible gotchas I may or may not be running into:**

- The router does *not* use MAC filtering.
- Using a static ip outside the router's DHCP range (192.168.2.70), I was able to connect and even get into the router's html configuration tool at 192.168.2.1.
- The box I'm trying to connect from has a wired interface (eth0). Any chance that the DHCP client request from wlan0 is not sent over the air in order to establish a DHCP ip connection on 192.168.2.0, but into my wired subnet (192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0)? There's no DHCP server on the wired subnet, so the DHCP request may just end up being lost in 192.168.1.0/24? How would I debug and rule out something like this?
- The box has Debian wheezy (7.0) installed. Having used the box in a wired subnet with static ip addresses, I may have forgotten to change a configuration somewhere that may be needed for dhclient to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with my setup.  My router (Linksys E2500) would not give a DHCP offer until the original DHCP lease for the machine's MAC expired.

To fix this, I had to manually remove the entry from my router's lease table and attempt to bring the wlan interface back up.

I'm not sure why this happens; perhaps someone more familiar with the way the hardware and DHCP works on Debian can enlighten us.

Comment: Hmmm... after manually changing my WiFi adapter's MAC address (ifconfig wlan0 down, ifconfig wlan0 hw ether *newmac*, ifconfig wlan0 up), dhclient was able to establish a connection and obtain an IP from the router. This seems to support your theory. I'll try some more things to make sure this is the root cause...

Comment: Check. This must have been the reason. As I'm typing this, I have diabled the wired interface (eth0), and the router has accepted my WiFi interface (wlan0), after the leases have all expired.

Comment: I'd only add that if the device has a DHCP reservation on the router you need to delete it and re-add.